# Why won't it let me challenge the next Sim to a chess match?

Tags: the-sims-3

My Sim is a child with level 10 in the Logic skill and the Chess Legend lifetime wish. When I use the phone, it gives me the option to call and invite over the next Sim for a chess match, like expected. However, once that Sim gets to the house, it doesn't actually let me challenge them to a match via the chess table. It only gives me the standard "Practice Chess" and "Play Chess with..." options like it normally would. I've tried inviting them over several times and still the same result. Why won't the game let me actually challenge the Sim in chess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently Sims 3 just likes to be confusing in this aspect. You can't actually challenge Sims in chess matches until you've reached the **Teen** stage in their life, so a Child is not capable of doing so (even though the option to invite them over still appears). Using a birthday cake to instantly age the Sim up to the Teen stage, then inviting the Sim over for chess, will make the option to actually challenge them appear when selecting the chess table.